# SQL Server : identity and autoincrement for varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my first question on this platform. I am working on a database project. I want to use autoincrement for my primary key for `id`, but also want to add an alphabet before it. Are there other ways to do it apart from using 2 columns declaring one as identity and casting the other? I have worked with stored procedures and triggers.

Thank you

PS: I want to do it using one column if possible

Comment: `IDENTITY` is for numerical values only. You could add an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, which receives the newly created row and then update your alphanumeric column.

Comment: How does this alphanumeric looks like?

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to do this with just one column.

The best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCompany
(
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
      CompanyID AS 'CMP-' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
      .... your other columns here....
)
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `tblCompany` without specifying values for `ID` or `CompanyID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCompany(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will increase your `ID` value, and `CompanyID` will contain values like `CMP-00001`, `CMP-00002`,...... and so on - automatically. The `CompanyID` column will be fill automatically, by SQL Server, upon inserting a new row - so there's no need for triggers or stored procedures or anything else - just this declaration in your table definition.

**UPDATE:** if you're using SQL Server **2012 or newer**, you can do it with just one column - if you also create a `SEQUENCE` - like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_CompanyID
AS INT
START WITH 1000
INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Company
(
    CompanyID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_CompanyID
        DEFAULT('CMP-' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SEQ_CompanyID AS VARCHAR(10))),
    CompanyName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ----- other columns here
)
```

Now if you make sure to insert with **omitting** the `CompanyID` column in the insert statement, like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Company (CompanyName)
VALUES ('Company #1'), ('Company ABC'), ('Company Three');
```

then you get `CMP-1001', 'CMP-1002` etc. as your `CompanyID`, again, automatically handled by SQL Server upon inserting a new row.

Comment: When I read "You won't be able to do this with just one column", I thought, "Sure you could, if you used a sequence..." and then there you were, right on that. +1