# Springboot integration test fails after upgrading from springboot 3.1.5 to 3.2.0

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-3

Everything works fine in Springboot 3.1.5 but...when I updrade to Springboot 3.2.0, I encounter error such as `Fail to load application context`

Database: MySQL

Unit test database: H2

I check the log and found that it was caused by this error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: 
Error executing DDL 
"create table guest_boot_notification (id varchar(255) generated by default 
as identity, link_id varchar(255), 
notification_lang varchar(255) check (notification_lang in ('EN','GE','ZH','ZH_TW')), type varchar(255) check (type in ('CHAIR','CABINET','TABLE','SOFA')), 
web_hook_url varchar(255), primary key (id))" 
via JDBC [Feature not supported: "CHARACTER VARYING(255)";]
```

Another error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: 
Operand of + is of type 'java.lang.Object' 
which is not a numeric type (it is not an instance of 
'java.lang.Number', 'java.time.Temporal', or 'java.time.TemporalAmount')
```

Anybody encounter such issue?
Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Maybe you check your database. Do you use H2? Spring-Boot 3.2.0 brings a lot of dependency upgrades https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes#dependency-upgrades. Please edit your post and add some information about the test database e.g. which vendor and version and the related dependencies.

Comment: hi @Easterwood, thanks for your reply, I updated my post, I am actually using mysql db, but in unit test its H2...

Comment: Use the same dbms in both cases, choosing a different one for test purposes makes no sense.

Comment: In my own investigation, the problem arises due to the upgrade of the hibernate-core library to version `6.3.1.Final` when springboot was upgraded from 3.1.5 to `3.2.0`. In this case, I appreciate any suggestions from springboot engineer out there on what steps should I take to address this...?

Comment: Occurs the error with H2 or MySQL or in both cases?

Comment: it occurs on both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generated by default` only supports numeric values, see [H2 SQL Grammer](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition) and [sequence option](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#sequence_option).

I tested the SQL with a H2 database and the `varchar(255)` type is not supported with `generated by default`. This is the case for your ID field. Maybe you provide a value generator e.g. with `@GeneratedValue(generator = "<name-of-a-generator")`.

Starting with [Hibernate Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#generated-identifiers) you could try to implement a [custom generator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#user-defined-generators). I found a short tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers). Maybe this prevents Hibernate from adding the `generated by default`.

I replaced the `varchar(255)` with `int` and the SQL is valid:

```
create table guest_boot_notification (id int generated by default
as identity, link_id varchar(255), 
notification_lang varchar(255) check (notification_lang in ('EN','GE','ZH','ZH_TW')), type varchar(255) check (type in ('CHAIR','CABINET','TABLE','SOFA')), 
web_hook_url varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

Another solution is described in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429755/sql-server-identity-and-autoincrement-for-varchar).

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! I do have @GeneratedValue(generator = "<name-of-a-generator"), but the generator is of no use, so I removed it. It fix the error.

Comment: How do you fixed it?

Comment: I removed the `generator = "genauto"` in`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "genauto")`